# Understanding degrees of freedom in relation to rank for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\bar{y})^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

So I'm looking at [this website](http://www.jerrydallal.com/LHSP/dof.htm) which states:

> One of the questions an instrutor [sic] dreads most from a mathematically unsophisticated audience is, "What exactly is degrees of freedom?" It's not that there's no answer. The mathematical answer is a single phrase, "The rank of a quadratic form."

And near the end:

> Okay, so where's the quadratic form? Let's look at the variance of a single sample. If $y$ is an $n$ by $1$ vector of observations, then
>   $$\sum(y_i - \bar{y})^2 = y^{\prime}My\text{, where }M = \begin{pmatrix}
> 1-\frac{1}{n} & -1/n & \cdot & -1/n \\
> -1/n          & 1-\frac{1}{n} & \cdot & -1/n \\
> \cdot         & \cdot         & \cdot & \cdot \\
> -1/n          & -1/n          & -1/n & 1-\frac{1}{n}
> \end{pmatrix}\text{.}$$
>   The number of degrees of freedom is equal to the rank of the $n$ by $n$ matrix $M$, which is $n-1$.

I will use $r$ to denote the rank and $C(A)$ to denote the column space of a matrix $A$.

From my notes, I have the definition $r(A) = r\left(C(A)\right)$, which is the number of vectors that create a basis for $C(A)$. Sure.

Let's consider column one:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1-\frac{1}{n}\\
-1/n \\
\cdot \\
-1/n
\end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{-1}{n}
\begin{pmatrix}
1-n \\
1 \\
\cdot \\
1 
\end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{-1}{n}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
\cdot \\
1 
\end{pmatrix} + \dfrac{-1}{n}\begin{pmatrix}
-n \\
0 \\
\cdot \\
0 
\end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{-1}{n}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
\cdot \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\cdot \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}\text{.}
$$
So based on what I'm seeing here, I'm guessing that a basis for $C(A)$ would be something like 
$$\mathscr{V} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
\cdot \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
\cdot \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
\cdot \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}, \cdots, \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\cdot \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
which consists of $n+1$ vectors. However, clearly $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
\cdot \\
1 
\end{pmatrix}$$ needs to be removed, since it is the sum of the other $n$ vectors, so I get that there are $n$ vectors in $\mathscr{V}$, and therefore $r(\mathscr{V}) = r(C(M)) = n$.

Where is the $n-1$ coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take en example: the matrix 
$$
A=\left[\matrix{1 & 1\\2 & 2}\right].
$$
Applying your method: the first column
$$
\left[\matrix{1 \\ 2}\right]=\left[\matrix{1 \\ 1}\right]+\left[\matrix{0 \\ 1}\right],
$$
and the second column
$$
\left[\matrix{1 \\ 2}\right]=2\left[\matrix{1 \\ 1}\right]-\left[\matrix{1 \\ 0}\right],
$$
hence, collecting all "basic" vectors
$$
\left\{\left[\matrix{1 \\ 1}\right],\left[\matrix{1 \\ 0}\right],\left[\matrix{0 \\ 1}\right]\right\}
$$
and removing the first dependent gives the rank being $2$.

Do you see the problem with your argument?

> The vectors you take as basic vectors do not all belong to the subspace. They span a larger subspace than $C(A)$.

Comment: Back to the drawing board it is. Clearly $r(A) = 1$ in your example. Do you have any suggestions as to how I should think of this problem?

Comment: @Clarinetist One quite standard way to calculate rank is to perform the Gauss elimination to get an echelon form of the matrix. Here it is quite easy. You can multiply each row by $n$ to avoid fractions.

Comment: $M = I_n + \frac{-1}{n}\mathbb{1}_{n \times n}$

Answer (score 1):

The sum of all the $n$ columns is $(0,0,0,\ldots,0)^T$ and so surely the column rank cannot be $n$ as you claim it to be?

Comment: I see. What was wrong with my approach?